# Floating images css only

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Is this [Link](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/images.html) possible without `javascript`?
I'm trying to learn `css` and `floating layouts`.
I've searched on the forums and people's links to this site, and even if this is looks like a good solution I would like to broaden my skills in `css` and `html`.

Comment: Try disabling Javascript on your browser and see if the site still works the way you think it should.  Then you'll know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`CSS3 Columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_multi-column_layouts) you can easily achieve the same result on modern browser:

Example jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ivumoq/1/edit

relevant CSS

```
body > div {
   -webkit-column-count:3; 
   -webkit-column-width:200px;
   -moz-column-count:3; 
   -moz-column-width:200px
   column-count:3; 
   column-width:200px;
}
```

You may also define the number of columns according to a specific mediaquery. E.g. if you wanto to display 4 columns when the viewport is larger that > `960px`

```
@media all and (min-width:960px) {
    body > div {
        -webkit-column-count:4; 
        -moz-column-count:4; 
        column-count:4;
    } 
}
```

So you could emulate the reflow of masonry on browser resize.

Example with mediaqueries: http://jsbin.com/ivumoq/2/edit

Otherwise, using float you need to define three floated containers (as three independent columns) and place approx.ly 1/3 of the images on each container.

Comment: And here's one more example how it could look http://jsfiddle.net/zJ6zg/1/ There's one problem you should know it doesn't work with IE

Comment: That's why I specified a second solution :) (Anyway I thought the question was related more on the existence of a pure css solution)

Comment: Fabrizio Calderan my comment was more for Designon. For you +1 for answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tYGde/)

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left-col">
        <div class="small"></div>
        <div class="medium"></div>
        <div class="large"></div>
        <div class="large"></div>
        <div class="medium"></div>
        <div class="small"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">
        <div class="large"></div>
        <div class="medium"></div>
        <div class="small"></div>
        <div class="small"></div>
        <div class="medium"></div>
        <div class="large"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    width:400px;
    height:auto !important;
    background:yellow;
}
.left-col {
    max-width:200px;
    height:0 auto;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.right-col {
    max-width:200px;
    height:0 auto;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.small {
    width:190px;
    margin:10px;
    height:100px;
    background:green;
    display:block;
}
.medium {
    width:190px;
    margin:10px;
    height:200px;
    background:blue;
    display:block;
}
.large {
    width:190px;
    margin:10px;
    background:brown;
    height:400px;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is possible, but you'll have to have different columns. If you use display: inline-block the images will not align properly, and if you float them, you'll have a problem when the first one on a row is taller then the last one.
I fiddled it up:

http://jsfiddle.net/VeecS/

one column html:

```
<div class="col">
    <h2>Column1</h2>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300X150" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300X320" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300X120" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.col {
    width:24%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```